# Replicated LDAP server

Tags: directoryservices, openldap, ldap-query

When we restart a replicated (consumer or mirrored) LDAP server, it accepts the connection from the clients even if it is out of sync.  Is it expected? i.e. can a client bind with an LDAP server which is not fully recovered?  If yes, then is there a way to disallow it?

Answer (score 1):

That's how OpenLDAP works. I'm not aware of any way to prevent it. If you use refreshAndPersist it can't get too far out of sync I would have thought, unless it's been down for a day or so.